# jQuery - append/replace event listeners (when event handlers are not known)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I tried to find an answer to my problem, but was not successful - apologies if the answer is very obvious:). Here is the premise of the issue I am trying to solve.

- I have lots of UI elements (buttons, hyperlinks etc) that have native events attached to them (eg, clicking a link executes a function)
- I do not have access to those event listeners, nor I know what functions/handlers need to be Invoked
- I would like to do a generic function which would:
  o   transverse thru DOM, find the UI elements like button or hyperlink, and attach additional listeners to it that would execute the same handlers/functions (eg, I want to attach “touchend” listeners that would execute the same handlers/functions as “click” event)

Is there a way for me to somehow find out what event handler(s) is(are) used for a particular UI element, and then append the new listener for same handler via .on() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quandary is bit open ended.

Read this: [Things you may not know about jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/).

You can access all event handlers bound to an element (or any object) through jQuery’s event storage:

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );
 
// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});
 
// You can see the actual functions which will occur
// on certain events; great for debugging!
```

P.S. I would recommend to learn the DOM better.

Comment: Thanks a mil, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for - I will try to implement this solution today or tomorrow and let you know...

Comment: @IvanS no probs! Glad it helped you `:)`

Comment: For anyone finding this now, as of `jQuery v1.8`, `$(element).data("events")` [has been removed](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).