# Is there a way to replace all click listeners with touchend listeners in JQuery and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm sure you've heard this a lot, but I can't seem to find a good solution.

Is there a way to swap any `click` listeners with `touchend` listeners?

Since my iPad web app is sizing itself to the screen automatically, I don't think our users (in-house, anyway) will need double tap to zoom, and the 300ms wait is really brutal.

Could I do something like

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).bind('touchend', function(e){
   e.currentTarget.click();
});
```

Or something similar that would affect the entire page / app globally? Ideally, I'd run this code only if I detect `touchEvent` capabilities on the page. (Although touchscreen monitors with a mouse kind of confuses things...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using AngularTouch (ngTouch).

This worked, but I had problems mixing:

- angularJS
- angularTouch
- jquery
- jqueryui (for draggable and droppable)
- jquery touchpunch (for mobile)

What I ended up doing was using: (in this order)

- jquery
- jqueryui
- jquery touchpunch
- angularjs
- [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

This allowed fast clicks and drag and drop on mobile!

Answer (score 2):

If your application is already developed, then one silver-bullet approach could be to insert a shim that globally handles touch events (while suppressing default mouse events) and dispatches the corresponding mouse events.

There are a few libraries out there that do this. One that I have used successfully is: **[fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js)**. It's simple to set up, pretty configurable, doesn't insert listeners on desktop browsers, and will remove that 300ms delay.

Comment: That's a great resource. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

include the module ngTouch (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) in your module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will I have to add the `ng-touch` directive to my buttons? Or will this swap `clicks` with `touches`?

Comment: it replaces the ng-click directive. so you don't need to do enything special to marke it work.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521047/jquery-append-replace-event-listeners-when-event-handlers-are-not-known), you could use this code:

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});

// You can see the actual functions which will occur
// on certain events; great for debugging!
```

To get to listeners and then replace/modify then. Hopefully it helps!